# Unable to import python modules

Tags: python, import, module, package

My project structure is like this:

```
--base
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
    mod2.py
    version.py
```

Contents of `__init__.py`:

```
from .version import __version__ as version

__version__ = version
```

mod2 contains a class called classA.

Inside mod1 I am importing classA like this:

```
mod1.py:

from base.mod2 import classA
```

However I get an error saying "No module named base".

Note: `import mod2` works. However, I want to use the absolute path approach, but it does not work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I am executing the python script from the `base` directory. Also, `base` is in `sys.path` (just verified).

**EDIT 2**: I want to import the class in a similar [way](https://github.com/user-cont/release-bot/blob/master/release_bot/releasebot.py#L26).

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: That's very helpful. But I don't want to use the complete path of the file. I want to try to implement something like [this](https://github.com/user-cont/release-bot/blob/master/release_bot/releasebot.py#L26)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 3**: If you want to import a submodule from within the package directory, which is `base`, you could use this (omitting the `base` part in the import) in the file/module `mod1.py`,

```
from mod2 import classA
```

The above solution also works with `run_test_1.py` and `run_test_2.py` scripts. Hope this helps =)

**UPDATE 2**: I will demonstrate the same approach by executing a python script from the `test` directory,

create a script called `run_test_1.py` under `test` directory following the same structure as "UPDATE 1", with the following contents:

```
from base.mod2 import classA
a = classA()
```

Also create a second script called `run_test_2.py` under `test` directory as well, with the following contents:

```
from base import mod1
mod1.classA()
```

Evaluate both scripts from your terminal like so,

```
$ cd ~/path/to/test/
$ python run_test_1.py
hello
$ python run_test_2.py
hello
```

As demonstrated you should get the output of "hello" on your terminal.

**UPDATE 1**: I created the same directory structure for your package like so under a directory called `test`,

```
-- test
    --base
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
        mod2.py
        version.py
```

Contents of `__init__.py` is the same as yours.

```
from .version import __version__ as version
__version__ = version
```

Contents of `mod1.py` is the same as yours,

```
from base.mod2 import classA
```

Contents of `mod2.py`:

```
class classA:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
```

Then using the `python` interpreter from the directory `test`, I tested the following,

```
>>> from base.mod2 import classA
>>> a = classA()
hello
```

If you are sure that `base` directory is in the `sys.path` then you could try this,

`from base import mod2`

Also I suggest you change `base` to something more informative for your project.

**EDIT**: I also suggest you check the ["Packages" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on the Python website, which also discusses how to load a submodule.

Comment: `from base import .mod2` in Python 3

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like you got the question wrong. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @James did you try to call it from `ipython` from the parent directory of `base` or even from a different directory since it's already in the path?

Comment: I am not using `iPython` but I am calling it from `base` directory.

Comment: Ok no problem, have you tried calling from a different directory, and double check that the `base` directory is in `sys.path` please.

Comment: Yes. base is in sys.path. I have printed and verified it. My guess is that Python is somehow not recognizing the package, even though I have a `__init__.py` there.

Comment: I tested with the same directory structure used in your answer, but I ran it from the parent directory of `base` not from inside `base` directory itself. Could you try this from the parent directory of `base`: `from base.mod2 import classA`

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if something is not clear in my answer, thanks.

Comment: Your solution is working because you are running it from the interactive shell, and not running mod2.py. However, I intend to execute mod2.py. Which is giving me an error

Comment: I will try to demonstrate it using a python script instead of interactive shell, give me a moment. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Please check my UPDATE 2. Thanks.  I used `Python 2.7.15rc1`

Comment: Sorry for being very picky, but I was talking about `mod2.py` which is in `base` directory. All your solutions work for me, but mod2.py is giving me the error. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to call `mod2.py` from inside `base`, could you elaborate more? Also the reason why people use packages is not to be able to call sub-modules from inside the package directory, I am just trying to help so let me know ;)

Comment: Also please tell us how are you running mod2.py, is it just like this: `python mod2.py` ?

Comment: @JamesBringer Ok if you must import the module from the `base` directory itself which is the package directory, you could just do this `from mod2 import classA` and it would work, please confirm if this is what you want